# Calabash Cucumber - Query a subview of a UITabBarButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, cucumber, calabash

I'm trying to have Cucumber query a `UIButton` that is a subview of a `UITabBarButton` but it can't find it. I assigned an accessibility ID and it appears in the Calabash console using `tree` command but trying to query it by ID directly fails.

Does anyone know how to have Cucumber access the subview? Or is this a limitation of Calabash?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

`query("UITabBarButton UIButton")` - this should show all UIButtons under UITabBarButton

`query("UITabBarButton id:'your_accessibility_id'")` - should show only the element with the accessibility ID.

If all fails, query for everything and search through the results, that might give you some clues to why it's not working. `query("*")`

Some useful information [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query-syntax/)

Hope it helps!